# submitting form with Mojo::UserAgent

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojo-useragent

I want to submit a form using [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) where the form has the following:

```html
<form action="/login" method="post" class="Login">
```

which has 2 inputs ids user and password

With WWW::Mechanize I am using something like this:

```
my $resp = $agent->submit_form(
    form_number => 4,
    fields => {
    user => $user,
    password => $passwd,
    }
);
```

On Mojo::UserAgent I see there is an option to submit a post request, something like:

```
my $tx = $ua->post(
    'https://metacpan.org/search' 
        => form => {q => 'mojo'}
);
```

How can I submit such a form with Mojo::UserAgent?

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear. Are you just looking for `my $tx = $ua->post('https://whatever.your.site.name.is/login' => form => { user => $user, password => $passwd })`?